# c++ using a different class for an argument?

Tags: c++, class, argument-passing

I have a simple question, when I'm writing the .h file of a class and want to pass an argument of type of a different class how should it be written?

For example:

```
#include "y.h"
class x
{
public :
void method( y &)
};
```

In `void method`, is that right? Or should it be written as `y::y&`?
And when it's implemented in a .cpp file?

Comment: That is right. You might want to give the argument a name, for clarity / self-documentation.

Comment: Thank you! so it will be basically typed the same way in both .h and .cpp file?

Comment: In the `.cpp` file it should look like `void x::method(y& p) {}`

Answer (score 1):

If your class is called `y` then what you have written is correct. The `::` syntax is for referencing names within namespaces or other classes. In this particular case, `y::y` would refer to the constructor of `y`, not the class itself.

There is no change to this within the implementation (.cpp) file - the name `y` references the same class in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

If do not take into account qualifier volatile then you have the following possibilies

```
void method( y &);
void method( const y &);
void method( y );
void method( const y * );
void method( y * );
```

Declaration

```
void method( const y );
```

declares the same function as

```
void method( y );
```

Also the method itself can have qualifier const. For example

```
void method( y &) const;
```

Also if the class name will be hidden then you can use the elaborated name. For example

```
void method( class y &) const;
```

This declaration

```
void method( y::y &);
```

is correct provided that the left y is the name of a namespace and the right y is the name of a class defined in the namespace.